# Regex Expression wrong

Tags: regex, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to extract the country (here Indonesia) from the following phrase:

```
<small class="text-muted">
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Football / </span>Indonesia / 
                            <span class="hidden-xs xh-highlight">Kick off: </span>11 Sep 2019, 11:30                            </small>
```

At the moment, I am just using the following command to extract the text:

```
.xpath('.//small[@class="text-muted"]/text()').extract()
```

What is the right regex command to extract just Indonesia?

Comment: This seems to be an XPath question and has nothing to do with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//small[@class="text-muted"]/span[@class="hidden-xs"]/following-sibling::text()
```

which has the result `Indonesia /`.
If you want to get rid of the slash, you have several possibilities:

1. Remove all slashes from the expression:

   ```
   normalize-space(translate(//small[@class="text-muted"]/span[@class="hidden-xs"]/following-sibling::text(),"/",""))
   ```
2. Use `substring-before()` to get the string before the slash:

   ```
   normalize-space(substring-before(//small[@class="text-muted"]/span[@class="hidden-xs"]/following-sibling::text(),"/"))
   ```
3. Use `substring-before()` to get the string before the first space:

   ```
   normalize-space(substring-before(//small[@class="text-muted"]/span[@class="hidden-xs"]/following-sibling::text()," "))
   ```

There are other XPath expressions that would work as well. Choose the one that fits best in your situation. The leading dot before the `//` is only necessary if you designate a relative path to the current node. In the above expressions I did assume that the lookup is global.

And, of course, these XPath expressions have to be surrounded by

```
.xpath('...').extract()
```

Comment: Hey zx485 - thanks for your answer. It is working. What do I have to do to extract everything after Kick off? I would like to extract "11 Sep 2019, 11:30 "

Comment: One way is to adjust the second @class value from `span[@class="hidden-xs"]` to `span[@class="hidden-xs xh-highlight"]` (or to `span[contains(@class,"xh-highlight")]`).

Comment: I am using the following command: `post.xpath('normalize-space(.//small[@class="text-muted"]/span[@class="hidden-xs xh-highlight"]/following-sibling::text())').extract()` But it is not working. I deleted the subtring-before function because it is not necessary here, is it?

Comment: I tested your expression and for me it does work. So, unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your error. I c/p'ed your expression and its result is `11 Sep 2019, 11:30`. I also checked my second variant and it does work, too. Because this seems to be a new problem arising, I suggest that you ask a new question with a good [mcve] to get this solved.

Comment: Okay - the class "hidden-xs xh-highlight" is wrong in the above mentioned code. Is is also the class "hidden-xs". I got the data with the following commands (maybe not that most efficient answer): `kickoff = post.xpath('.//small[@class="text-muted"]/span[@class="hidden-xs"]/following-sibling::text()').re('([^/]+$)')
      kickoff = [x.strip(' ') for x in kickoff]
      kickoff = [kickoff[1]]`

Comment: Well, if the second `span` has (contrary to the sample above) the same @class as the first one, you can also make use of an index and apply this XPath expression: `.//small[@class="text-muted"]/span[@class="hidden-xs"][2]/following-sibling::text()` which results in `11 Sep 2019, 11:30`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, from `bs4` importing `BeautifulSoup`, we could extract the country, if that'd be OK:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

string="""
<small class="text-muted">
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Football / </span>Indonesia / 
                            <span class="hidden-xs xh-highlight">Kick off: </span>11 Sep 2019, 11:30                            </small>
A

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser').find_all('small')[0].text

print(re.findall(r'[^/]+/\s*([^/]+?)\s*/', soup)[0])
```

#### Output

```
Indonesia
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is, how much do you know about the input? You obviously don't know that it contains "Indonesia", but are all the other parts of the input completely fixed? For example, does the text you are looking for always immediately follow a span element with content `Football /`?

If that's the case then you can do

```
//small[@class="text-muted"]/span[. = Football / ']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```